# How does equals() method work in Java

Tags: java, overriding, equals

The `equals` method compares whether two object values are equal or not. My question is how it compares the two objects? How can it tell the two objects are equal or not? I want to know based on what it compares the two objects. I am not including the `hashCode` method.

Comment: If you need to compare objects, I'd recomend you to take a look on guava library object helper: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained

Answer (score 6):

The default implementation, the one of the class `java.lang.Object`, simply tests the references are to the same object :

```
150    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
151        return (this == obj);
152    }
```

The reference equality operator is described like this in the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2) :

> At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both
>   null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result
>   is false.

This default behavior isn't usually semantically satisfying. For example you can't test equality of big Integer instances using `==` :

```
Integer a = new Integer(1000);
Integer b = new Integer(1000);
System.out.println(a==b); // prints false
```

That's why the method is overridden :

```
722     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
723         if (obj instanceof Integer) {
724             return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
725         }
726         return false;
727     }
```

which enables this :

```
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // prints true
```

Classes overriding the default behavior should test for semantic equality, based on the equality of identifying fields (usually all of them).

As you seem to know, you should override the `hashCode` method accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Consider following example,

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String passportNumber;
    String socialSecurityNumber;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        boolean isEqual = e1.equals(e2);  // 1
        System.out.println(isEqual);
    }
}
```

In the code at comment //1 it calls inherited `equals` method from Object class which is simply comparing references of `e1` and `e2`. So it will always give `false` for each object created by using `new` keyword.

Following is the method excerpt from Object

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

For comparing equality check JLS has given `equals` method to override in our class. It is not final method. JLS doesn't know on what basis programmar wants to make two objects equal. So they gave non-final method to override.
`hashcode` does not play role to check object's equality. `hashcode` checks/finds the Bucket where  object is available. we use `hashcode` in hashing technique which is used by some classes like HashMap..

*If two object's hashcode are equals that doesn't means two objects are equal.* 
*For two objects, if `equals` method returns true then hashcode must be same.*

You will have to override `equals` method to decide on which basis you want object `e1` and `e2` in above code is equal. Is it on the basis of `passportNumber` or `socialSecurityNumber`  or the combination of `passportNumber+socialSecurityNumber`?

```
I want to know based on what it compares the two objects.
```

Answer is, by default with the help of inherited `Object` class's `equals` method it compares two object's reference equality by using == symbol. Code is given above.

Answer (score 0):

logically, equals does not compare objects (however you can do anything with it), it compares values. for object comparison there is '==' operator

Comment: I don't agree. Equals compares objects the way it was created. As dystroy explained - usually it compares values, but not always, and not always all of them. E.g. for entities equals method usually compares only the id field.

Comment: i mentioned, 'logically' & 'you can do anything'. 'equals' is suppose to compare objects 'meaningfully' otherwise you mightn't have '==' for objects.