# equals() method and object comparing

Tags: java, equals, equals-operator

I was studying basics of java and saw equals() method and wrote this code

```
public class EqualsTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = new String("this");
    String str2 = new String("this");

    Object obj1 = new Object(6);
    Object obj2 = new Object(6);

    System.out.println(str == str2);
    System.out.println(str.equals(str2));

    System.out.println(obj1 == obj2);
    System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
    }
}
```

and this.

```
public class Object {
public int num;

public Object(int num) {
    this.num = num;
    }

}
```

When I run the code, I get the result saying

```
false
true
false
false
```

I could understand why I got first two result. (false and true) 
'==' operator compares whether str and str2 are referencing the same instance and equals() method compares the actual value inside.

However I could not understood why I got false for both

```
obj1 == obj2;
obj1.equals(obj2);
```

I thought since they both have the value 6 with them,

```
obj1.equals(obj2);
```

this line should've given the true as a result.

Can someone please explain this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542656/how-does-equals-method-work-in-java

Comment: This is a dup.e

Comment: hmm..I would like to know why System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)) is returning false. Anyone please explain.